# How to plot the position of ethzasl_ptam in rqt_plot?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-jade, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS node (ethz-ptam) which publishes a topic `/vslam/pose` which is of type `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance` message. Running:

```
rostopic type /vslam/pose | rosmsg show
```

gives the following:

```
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance pose
  geometry_msgs/Pose pose
    geometry_msgs/Point position
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
    geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
      float64 w
  float64[36] covariance
```

I'd like to use rqt_plot to plot a field (say Point position `x`). But I tried everything to "call" it in rqt_plot, but it doesn't work, the rqt_plot window shows like it should but the field is not plotted. From `rostopic echo /vslam/pose` I know that it is being published, so everything is working except rqt_plot. Also if I write inside the text-input-field in rqt_plot, like they say in the docs (`topic-name/field:field:field`): `/vslam/pose/x` or `/vslam/pose/x:y:z` nothing shows. According to the tutorials, in rqt_plot you should be able to hit the `+`Button next to the text-input-field, but this one is never active in my case, so it can't be pressed.

I am pretty sure that I am making some kind of mistake in referencing the message field  (like `x`). But since I tried all variants I could think of,  I'd really apprechiate some advice on how to do this and call/reference this field so that the position fields are displayed in rqt_plot.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333733/how-to-plot-the-position-of-ethzasl_ptam-in-rqt_plot-?/) by [Curiosity](https://answers.ros.org/users/44263/curiosity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you have seen in the docs is wrong, can you link your doc ? In the official documentation of the rqt_plot package there is this [note](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot#Note_for_the_input_value_syntax) specifying the proper syntax.

The link says :

> The input value should be the full path to the value

So in `rqt_plot` you need to type `/topic_name/field/field`...

If you want to plot the x coordinate from your topic you need to type :

```
/vslam/pose/pose/pose/position/x
```

NB : There are 3 `pose` because the output of `rosmsg show` seems to indicate that your topic `/vslam/pose` publish `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped` messages instead of `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance` as you said. That means the first `pose` is from the topic name, the second one is the field of type `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance` and the last one for the `geometry_msgs/Pose` field.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Curiosity](https://answers.ros.org/users/44263/curiosity/) on 2019-09-26**:
I would link the post I found regarding the syntax, but somehow now I can't find it anymore. Really stupid since I am sure about what I saw there and posted in my question. But someone must have cleared the browser history of this lab computer. Sorry.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-09-26**:
No problem, even in the official documentation it can be misunderstanding as it's not the same syntax when using `rqt_plot` in command line or with `GUI`.